# Written code that converts decimal to hexadecimal - but wrong order output

Tags: java, string, printing, output

I have written a code that will convert a decimal number to a hexadecimal. Let's take as example the decimal number `123456`. My code will give output `042e1`, so the total wrong order of the correct result `1e240`.

My question, what I need to do to change the order of my output? I planned to convert to `String` and use `new StringBuilder(hi).reverse().toString()`. But this seems too complicated, I mean, how shall I take my outputs and convert them to `string`..? There must be an easier way.

I hope you can help me. I'm very happy I managed to get that far without any help, but I don't know how to get thisy work. This is no homework so feel free to help if you have some time :)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Convert{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double x = input.nextInt();
        double result = x;
        do{
            result = result / 16;
            int temp = (int)result;
            double rest = result*16-temp*16;
            if((int)rest == 10){
                System.out.print('a');
            }
            if((int)rest == 11){
                System.out.print('b');
            }
            if((int)rest == 12){
                System.out.print('c');
            }
            if((int)rest == 13){
                System.out.print('d');
            }
            if((int)rest == 14){
                System.out.print('e');
            }
            if((int)rest == 15){
                System.out.print('f');
            }
            if((int)rest != 10 && (int)rest != 11 && (int)rest != 12 && (int)rest != 13 && (int)rest != 14 && (int)rest != 15){
                System.out.print((int)rest);
            }
        }while((int)result != 0);   
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with reversing the data you currently have? what exactly is the issue you need help with?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw I don't know how I can reverse it :(

Comment: but you've already provided an example showing how to reverse it? or do you want the order to display properly without reversing?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw How would you use that command in my code?

Comment: see my answer for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to make a **[`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)** object:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); // place this before the do while block
```

then within each if block do this:

```
if((int)rest == 10){
     builder.append("a");
}

if((int)rest == 11){
    builder.append("b");
}

if((int)rest == 12){
    builder.append("c");
}

....
....
```

Considering you've mentioned:

> My code will give output 042e1, so the total wrong order of the
>   correct result 1e240.

then after the do while loop, simply **[`reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse())** it to yield the output `1e240`:

```
System.out.println(builder.reverse());
```